# Calling servlet from another servlet

Tags: java, servlets, urlconnection

I have two servlets which are running on different tomcat servers.

I and trying to call a  servlet1 from servlet2 in the following way and wanted to write an object to output stream.

```
URL url=new URL("http://msyserver/abc/servlet1");
URLConnection con=url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream os=con.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os);
oos.writeObject(pushEmailDTO);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

The problem is that i am unable to hit the servlet? I cannot figure out what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot unnderstand but it worked by adding the following line in the code.

```
con.getExpiration();
```

like this

```
URL url=new URL("http://msyserver/abc/servlet1");
URLConnection con=url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.getExpiration();//<----------
OutputStream os=con.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os);
oos.writeObject(pushEmailDTO);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

Comment: For new visitors , may be this could help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844535/why-do-you-have-to-call-urlconnectiongetinputstream-to-be-able-to-write-out-to

Answer (score 6):

You must create a connection via `url.connect()` before you can read/send data. This is counter-intuitive since the name `openConnection()` suggests that it does that already but the docs say:

> In general, creating a connection to a URL is a multistep process:
>
> 1. `openConnection()`
> 2. Manipulate parameters that affect the connection to the remote resource.
> 3. connect()
> 4. Interact with the resource; query header fields and contents.

This is why `getExpiration()` makes it work: It calls `connect()` for you.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error you are getting? Check that the address is correct. If the remote server is running in a port other than 80, then take this into consideration when building the URL.

May also I suggest to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html) instead of URLConnection.

Comment: I am not getting any exception every line executes successfully. Also the servlet is running on the exact url that i am passing in the code mentioned.