# Transfering text data to a web server using Java

Tags: java, ftp, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I'm trying to write to a text file on my web server using HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(). I have tried this on two different servers without success.

I have added a FileWriter to test the InputStream, and that file is created on a local directory correctly, but nothing is showing up on the in the web server directory, even with all password protection off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.myWebsite.com/myFile.txt");

           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                try {
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);


                    OutputStream in = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

                     InputStream fin1;
                        try {
                            fin1 = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/fileToRead.txt");
                            FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/fileToWrite.txt");

                            int data = fin1.read();
                            while(data != -1) {

                            fWriter.write(data);
                            in.write(data);
                              data = fin1.read();
                            }



                            fWriter.flush();
                            fWriter.close();

                            fin1.close();

                            in.flush();
                            in.close();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e31) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                    finally {
                     urlConnection.disconnect();
                   }
            } catch (IOException e4) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e4.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to authentication in your code. Doesn't that strike you as odd?

Comment: What type of error messages are you seeing in the logs?  I suggest you set your logging levels to DEBUG and watch them while running this code.  Also, is this code on the same server that you're trying to write the file to?  Also, what's the difference between `myFile.txt`, `fileToRead.txt` and `fileToWrite.txt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call getInputStream() on the urlConnection in order to get the output stream to flush out the socket to the remote server.

See the discussion here: [Why do you have to call URLConnection#getInputStream to be able to write out to URLConnection#getOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844535/why-do-you-have-to-call-urlconnectiongetinputstream-to-be-able-to-write-out-to-u)

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the IOException (Right after the IOException) but are not doing anything with it. At least print the stack trace.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a comment instead of an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apache's Http Client http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Much easier than getting URLConnection to work.