# Android POST Message Doesn't get Sent

Tags: android, html, post

I've encountered a rather strange error. I've written an android application that uploads an simple text file to a server. The code for the connection is as follows:

```
try {
    URL = new URL(myURL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+"---");
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutPutstream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.writeBytes(<my post request>);
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    connection.connect();
}
```

When I run this method, the post request is never sent over to the server. Nothing shows up on wireshark and if I look in logcat, there are no errors and the connection gets made fine, the POST message is just never sent. However, if I add a simple line right after the connection.connect() such as:

```
connection.getResponseCode();
```

Suddenly the POST message gets sent over no problem. What's going on here? Am I required to get a response code in order for the message to get sent over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Why do you have to call URLConnection#getInputStream to be able to write out to URLConnection#getOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844535/why-do-you-have-to-call-urlconnectiongetinputstream-to-be-able-to-write-out-to-u)
   In short you must call getInputStream() and close it. getResponseCode() is also working because it requires an established connection.
2. You do not need to call

   connection.connect();
   which is redundant.

You can get working sample from here: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139

Answer (score 0):

You set doInput to true. Maybe the url connection waits for an input because of that. Try to set it to false. But I could also be wrong. It is just a guess.