# Sending Java POST request without calling getInputStream()

Tags: java, post, io

I would like to send a POST request in Java. At the moment, I do it like this:

```
URL url = new URL("myurl");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
ps.println("key=" + URLEncoder.encode("value"));
// we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
con.getInputStream();  
ps.close();
```

I do not understand why I have to call con.getInputStream() in order to actually send the request. If I do not call it, the request is not sent.

Is there a problem using PrintStream? It should not matter if I take a PrintStream, PrintWriter or something else, right?

Comment: Try replacing that call with `ps.flush()`.

Comment: I already tried it, but it did not help. Every call of ps.println() already calls flush()...

Comment: Sorry, now I found the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844535/why-do-you-have-to-call-urlconnectiongetinputstream-to-be-able-to-write-out-to-u/4844926#4844926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a post of another thread answered my question. Sorry, but I found it too late. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844535/why-do-you-have-to-call-urlconnectiongetinputstream-to-be-able-to-write-out-to-u/4844926#4844926).

PS: Unfortunately, Stackoverflow added my last answer to the question as a comment, because my answer was too short. And it is not possible to mark a comment as the correct answer... Hope this one is long enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

URL represents some source.

URLConnection represents  a connection to the resource.

you need call connection.connect() to connect the connection

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
con.setDoInput (false);
```

before writing to the output.

P.S.: and you should also call con.connect () as swanliu says.

**Update**
This is what I came up with

```
    private static final void sendPostRequest (final String urlAddress, String key, String value) throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL (urlAddress);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection ();
        con.setDoOutput (true);
        con.setDoInput (false);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream (con.getOutputStream ());
        ps.println (key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode (value, "UTF-8"));
        ps.flush ();
        con.connect ();
        ps.close ();
    }
```

I checked with WireShark that a tcp connection is being established and that closed. But don't know how check that the server received the request.
If you have a quick way to check it you may try that code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way.

```
con.setDoOutput(true);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
ps.print("&client_id="+ 2);
ps.print("&amount="+10);
ps.flush();
ps.close();
```