# Java HTTP full duplex

Tags: java, http, post, jax-rs, httpurlconnection

I have a RESTful web service running on Jersey (GlassFish 3.1.1). This one's a bit unusual - it uses HTTP streaming. The client and server have a long running conversation in which they keep sending each other messages encoded as XML tags. The main reason for doing this is so the server can push to the client.

I have a test client that uses `HttpURLConnection`. The problem is that the either the client's `OutputStream` or server's `InputStream` are being closed prematurely. When I try to send a bit of XML from the client, I get a `ProtocolException` thrown (cannot write output after reading input).

When I test using WizTools RESTClient, I can post an XML request, but this tool doesn't allow for keeping the connection alive. But at least I know the web service is functioning at least in this scenario. (It's probably just fine in the streaming scenario; my guess is the `HttpURLConnection` is letting me down.

Is there a way to make the HttpURLConnection stay alive and give me the chance to actually send something to the `OutputStream`? And, on top of that, is there a way to allow it to keep writing to the `OutputStream` even after it has received data via the `InputStream`?

**Update:**

It looks like `HttpURLConnection` is enforcing the conventional usage of HTTP, namely that a client cannot process the response until it has completely sent the request (and closed the output stream). Is there an alternative that will allow for the request and response to temporally overlap? I just started looking at Apache HttpClient, but I haven't yet found anything to indicate it's possible, so I'm not sure if I'm wasting my time.

Comment: Are you trying to keep *both* connections alive?  I would think that you should only need to keep the "server --> client" connection open in order to push data to the client.  When the client needs to send data to the server, you can probably just send a "regular" HTTP request and then close the connection.

Comment: Thanks @Michael There is only one connection. This isn't strictly one-way server push. It's more like the server asks the client a question and the client answers. While I could have a separate connection for sending messages from client to server, persistent or otherwise, I'd rather avoid that complexity if I can.

Comment: No, I think that's the problem.  You need two separate connections.  One connection for pushing the questions to the client.  And another connection for sending the answers to the server.

Comment: @Michael, that certainly seems to be the case with `HttpURLConnection`. I'm not convinced that Jersey isn't willing to play call on this, so perhaps I should look for alternatives to `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: From the description, your service is not RESTful.

Comment: @Steve Using a plain old servlet on the server (instead of Jersey), and using `HttpURLConnection` on the client might do the trick.  Like you said in a comment to @AlfredoO, Jersey probably doesn't give you fine-grained control over opening/closing/flushing connections (although there might be advanced ways of configuring Jersey to fit your needs).

Comment: @artbristol Yes, I suppose I'm a long way of REST. I guess I said RESTful simply because I'm using Jersey. @Michael, I actually think I'll have better luck with Jersey than HttpURLConnection. The fact that Jersey allows for the body to be passed as an `InputStream` suggests the streaming scenario is possible. This was probably provided to support large file uploading.

Comment: @SteveTaylor Umm I think you have it backwards...HttpURLConnection has methods that let you stream the request body and response body (`getOutputStream()` and `getInputStream()` respectively).

Comment: @Michael Yes `HttpURLConnection` has those streams, but it expects you to close the `OutputStream` before reading the `InputStream`, otherwise it throws a `ProtocolException` telling you exactly that (cannot write output after reading input).

Comment: @SteveTaylor Yes, that makes sense.  That is how HTTP works.  The client sends a request to the server.  Once the server has received the *complete* request, it sends the response to the client.  You can't stream both the request and response at the same time because the server can't start sending the response until it has received the entire request.

Comment: @Michael Large requests are received in many packets. Since servlets can be called before the entire request is received (think large file upload) and will process the input as it comes in, it's not hard to imagine that Jersey could figure out the method to call from the URL and pass in an `InputStream` containing the body of the request. Indeed, JAX-RS/Jersey allows for this. So, it's quite technically possible for the server to start sending a response before it finishes reading the request. The only issue I'm having is that **`HttpURLConnection` is explicitly forbidding it**.

Comment: @SteveTaylor Ehh, I don't know about that.  Have you tried doing this with Jersey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to write more data after reading from the `InputStream` because this does not follow the nature of **HTTP Protocol** which is **Request-Response**. Check more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844535/why-do-you-have-to-call-urlconnectiongetinputstream-to-be-able-to-write-out-to#answer-4844926).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I read it and take the point. However, there are many ways we stretch the HTTP protocol already, one of them being server push. The accepted answer in that link seems to speak of `HttpURLConnection` specifically rather than what is and isn't possible over HTTP. It may be that, indeed, Jersey doesn't call the resource method, passing in the `InputStream` containing the body until the entire request is received. If that's the case, then I'll have to use two connections. Until then, I'm interested in exploring alternatives to `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: An alternative would be Http Components Client http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Comment: Thanks @Alfredo O. Reading it now.

Comment: I accepted the answer despite it not being what I want to hear. Although I maintain that it probably is possible using something other than `HttpURLConnection`, it probably opens up a whole can of worms. I am now using two connections (one GET, one POST) and it's working well. I guess that's the price to pay for shoehorning this into HTTP.

Comment: There is no reason the http connection can't be reused. See Http Keep-Alive for one example. Of course, that doesn't mean Java supports it but don't go blaming the protocol