# Error 500 occurs if I get InputStream before writing to connection

Tags: java, http, httprequest, httpurlconnection

The code below

```
OutputStream outputWeb = conn.getOutputStream();

File file = new File("myfile");
InputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(file);

InputStream inputWeb = conn.getInputStream();           

while((ch=inputFile.read()) >= 0) {
    outputWeb.write(ch);
}
```

causes `IOException` with message "Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: myurl" just at the line where InputStream is taken from the connection.

While code below does not cause any exceptions and works fine

```
OutputStream outputWeb = conn.getOutputStream();

File file = new File("myfile");
InputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(file);

while((ch=inputFile.read()) >= 0) {
    outputWeb.write(ch);
}

InputStream inputWeb = conn.getInputStream();
```

The only difference is that taking input stream located after some writing to connection.

How one can deduce this from API contract? What is happening and why?

**conn configuration**

```
URL url = new URL("https://myurl");
HttpURLConnection conn;

// creating http connection 
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "audio....");
```

**UPDATE**

It is clear in principle now, but I still wish to see this in API contract. I.e. it should be written somewhere, that I can't gen input stream until write something. Implementations can allow this in any case, just obliging readers of that stream to wait.

Comment: A good answer explaining why this is happening and how to get around it (which you already know): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4844926/680925

Comment: You might want to consider `commons-io` library and `IOUtils.copy(InputStream, OutputStream)` method instead of copying content byte by byte, which can be *very* inefficient.

Comment: @Perception So it doesn't possible in HTTP, that server answers something before I finish posting? It is not possible, for example, to make HTTP converters which respond with partially data while posting still occurs?

Comment: @Dims - HTTP is a request-response protocol. A given response will only be sent ***after*** its corresponding request has been fully received. Aka, a complying server will ***never*** begin sending a response before it has completely received the full request from the client.

Comment: @Dims Not forbidden by spec. But most clients are single threaded, they won't start reading response until the entire request is written. Therefore the server cannot risk to respond before the request is drained; unless it knows the client is reading concurrently. Another mechanism is 100-continue; it's not widely implemented in clients either.

Comment: @irreputable - section 6 of RFC 2616 clearly states that a server should only respond ***after*** reading and interpreting the HTTP request message.

Comment: @Perception, it's not very clear. also search "before reading the entire request body" in the rfc.

Comment: @irreputable - Section says and I quote - 'After receiving and interpreting a request message, a server responds with an HTTP response message.'. Not sure how much clearer it has to be.

Comment: @Perception It can be much clearer by a all-capital MUST