# HTTP Post Json in Java

Tags: java, json, post, bufferedreader, httpurlconnection

I wanted to POST a json to a URL. I've found the following code, which works fine for me:

```
public void post(URL url, String json) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(json.getBytes());
            os.close();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I only want to POST and I don't care about the response. So, when I try to remove the second part (reading with the BufferedReader) it doesn't work anymore:

```
public void post(URL url, String json) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(json.getBytes());
            os.close();     
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

**[Try Flushing out the Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29)**

```
public void flush()
           throws IOException
```

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be
>   written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an
>   indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by
>   the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately
>   be written to their intended destination.

Before Closing the OutputStream , flush it out

```
os.flush(); --> This will flush your stream
os.close();
```

Comment: I don't think flushing helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844535/why-do-you-have-to-call-urlconnectiongetinputstream-to-be-able-to-write-out-to

Comment: As you can see in the first code I didn't need os.flush() to work correctly. And no, it doesn't help in the second code.